# Run a Perl script with options recursively through a directory

Tags: perl, shell

Given is a directory with a large number of files.

Also given is a Perl script that I want to run on each file of the directory. But this Perl script has options.

```
FILES=absolutepathtomyfiles/*
PROGRAMME=absolutepathtoperlscript/script.pl;
for f in $FILES
do
  if [[ $f == *.txt ]]; then
    absolutepathtoperlscript/script.pl -infile=$f -replace #both necessary options
  fi
done
```

Comment: What is wrong with the approach that you've chosen?  Does something not work?  What exactly does not work?

Comment: This seems to be a mix of perl and bash syntax

Comment: `if [[ $f == *.txt ]]` won't work. The cheapest way to get that is use `FILES=absolutepathtomyfiles/*.txt` in the first line.

Comment: `find | xargs perl script.pl`

Comment: @RobEarl: it's not that easy because he has more arguments. If any, then `find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -I FILE perl script.pl -infile=FILE -replace`, and that won't work if you don't have GNU xargs.

Answer (score 1):

If there are spaces or other strange characters in file names, you may have problems using the `for` construct. You could do this:

```
for file in /absolute/path/to/myfiles/*.txt
do
   [[ -f "$file"  ]] || continue
   /absolute/path/to/perl/script/script.pl -infile="$file" -replace
done
```

Note the `[[ -f "$file" ]] || continue`. This says that if `$file` is not a file, skip that file. It's similar to this:

```
if [[ -f "$file" ]]
then
    continue;
fi
```

If this doesn't work, try this:

```
export PS4="\$LINENO: "
for file in /absolute/path/to/myfiles/*.txt
do
   [[ -f "$file"  ]] || continue
   set -xv  # Turn on debugging
   /absolute/path/to/perl/script/script.pl -infile="$file" -replace
   set +xv  # Turn off debugging
done
```

This will print out your exact command line you're passing to your Perl script and may help you figure out what your issue could be.